# Mapping JSON data to Java objects

Tags: java, json

I have been trying to map JSON data to Java objects, with the JSON file on my PC, but it always throws the exception:

`org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "title" (Class MovieResponse), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: C:\M.json; line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: MovieResponse["title"])`

My data class:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class MovieResponse{
  private String title;
  private Integer year;
  @JsonProperty("mpaa_rating")
  private String mpaaRating;
  private Integer runtime;
  @JsonProperty("critics_consensus")
  private String criticsConsensus;

  public String getTitle(){
    return title;
  }
  public String setTitle(String t){
    return title = t;
  }

  public Integer getYear(){
    return year;
  }
  public Integer setYear(Integer y){
    return year = y;
  }

  public String getMpaa(){
    return mpaaRating;
  }
  public String setMpaa(String mp){
    return mpaaRating = mp;
  }

  public Integer getRuntime(){
    return runtime;
  }
  public Integer setRuntime(Integer r){
    return runtime = r;
  }

  public String getCritics(){
    return criticsConsensus;
  }
  public String setCritics(String c){
    return criticsConsensus = c;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "MovieResponse[title="+title+",year="+year+",mpaa_Rating="+mpaaRating+",runtime="+runtime+",critics_Consensus="+criticsConsensus
            +"]";
  }
}
```

My mapper class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import java.net.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Movie{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
 MovieResponse a = new MovieResponse();
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 try{

     MovieResponse response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("C:\\M.json"), MovieResponse.class);
 }catch(MalformedURLException u){
    u.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(IOException i){
    i.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
```

The json file contains following data:

```
{
  "title": "Toy Story 3",
  "year": 2010,
  "mpaa_rating": "G",
  "runtime": 103,
  "critics_consensus": "Deftly blending comedy, adventure, and honest emotion, Toy Story 3 is a rare second sequel that really works."
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using the Jackson library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of problems I see in your code:

1. The `@JsonIgnoreProperties` attribute should be put above the `MovieResponse` class, not the `Movie` class. Check out the [documentation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html), most notably what is said about the "ignoreUnknown" property, defaulted to false:

   > public abstract boolean **ignoreUnknown**
   >
   > Property that defines whether it is ok to just ignore any unrecognized
   >   properties during deserialization. If true, all properties that are
   >   unrecognized -- that is, **there are no setters or creators that accept
   >   them** -- are ignored without warnings (although handlers for unknown
   >   properties, if any, will still be called) without exception.
2. Your setters should not return any value, this may explain why Jackson does not see a "title" setter. Here is how the setter for "title" should be:

   ```
   public void setTitle(String t) {
       title = t;
   }
   ```
3. Not a reason for it to NOT work, but you are declaring your object mapper twice, consider using your mapper instead of instanciating a new one:

   ```
   MovieResponse response = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\M.json"), MovieResponse.class);
   ```

Edit: here's your fixed code I think:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import java.net.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

public class Movie {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MovieResponse response;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        response = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\M.json"), MovieResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I got where the error was , and edited it in the question,  now the code is running without any errors/eceptions, but not showing any output.

Comment: After you've read the value consider displaying it. For example: System.out.println("response" + response.toString());

Comment: I don't know why , but when I write System.out.println() in the class , it shows an error , cannot find symbol , symbol: class out in NetBeans

Answer (score 1):

This will work too

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
MovieResponse response = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\M.json"), MovieResponse.class);
```