# how can i map my json values to pojo with respect to json values

Tags: java, json, jaxb, pojo

I have genentated java pojo class from xsd file using jaxb,i have json data now how can i map my json values to pojo with respect to json values. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jackson Api is what you need

- Jackson api will automatically take care of Mapping depending upon names of Class and instance variables.
- Use @JsonProperty annotation over the instance Variable if You need customised Name

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;                     
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Pojo varObj = mapper.readValue(new File("c://temp/example.json"), Pojo.class);
```

References:

1. [Learn Basics of Jackson API](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/16/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)
2. [How to use @JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090464/mapping-json-data-to-java-objects)