# What data structure can hold the following data?

Tags: java, json

What can hold the below data in Java? HashMap of a HashMap?
I need to create a Java class that can hold such information.

```
{
  "data" : {
    "subdata" : [ {
      "attribute" : "1",
      "value" : "2",
      "operator" : "3"
    }, {
      "attribute" : "4",
      "value" : "5",
      "operator" : "6"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can always deserialize to a Map<String, Object> a json. But if your code is going to always have that exact structure, then you are better off to create proper classes!

Comment: Don't give up java type safety. Create a class for each type of object instead of raw map.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090464/mapping-json-data-to-java-objects

Answer (score 3):

You can always deserialize to a Map a json. But if your code is going to always have that exact structure, then you are better off to create proper classes!

```
class DataContainer {
   Data data;
}

class Data {
  List<Detail> subdata;
}

class Detail {
  String attribute;
  String operator;
  String value;
}
```

Remember to add whatever JSON annotation your parser needs.